# Does $\log(E[U]) = E[\log(U)]$?

Tags: expectation

In particular, I have

$$u = e^{-\gamma c_{t}}$$

Is it true that ($c_{t} > 0 \ \gamma \in \mathbb{R})$,

$$\log(\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\gamma c_{t}} \right]) = \mathbb{E}\left[\log(e^{-\gamma c_{t}}) \right]$$

where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation.

So, I know that $u$ is convex, and I am pretty sure that from Jensen's inequality,

$$\log(\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\gamma c_{t}} \right]) \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\log(e^{-\gamma c_{t}}) \right]$$

But it doesn't seem like I can produce a strict equality.

EDIT: Some additional info, $y_{t}$ is i.i.d.

$$c_{t} = \frac{r}{1+r}\left(A_{t}+y_{t}+\frac{1}{r}\bar{y} \right)-\pi(r,\gamma)$$

And, $y_{t} = \bar{y}-\epsilon_{t}$ and finally, $E_{t-1}[\epsilon_{t}] = 0$

This is part of a homework question, however, my question in particular is just something that would make a potential proof for the problem make much more sense (so I am not asking a solution to a homework problem, but help with a method I am using to solve a homework problem)

Comment: No, "log" is not linear.  Try an example where $U$ is not deterministic, the simplest one possible.  If you cannot explicitly compute a single example of this, then you are in over your head.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality (..."Notice that the equality holds if and only if [rv] is constant (degenerate random variable) or [function] is linear"